# How do I run a setup.py file without being in its directory?

Tags: python, python-3.x

To install a package that includes a setup.py file, usually you cd into the root directory where setup.py is located and then run the following:

```
python setup.py install
```

Now my problem is that I'm building an addon for another application, and while I can install "normal" package via code with the following:

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", package])
```

I also have to install a couple custom made packages, and if I try to do it like this:

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "/MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/setup.py", "install"])
```

I get the following error: `Error while finding module specification for 'MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/setup.py' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/setup')`

What is annoying me is that if I manually cd into the directory and simply run `python setup.py install` from the cmd it works just fine.

So the problem seems to be passing the relative path to the `setup.py` file, but as I said, considering this is an addon I **need** to install that `setup.py` from code. Any solution?

Comment: One suggestion is setting the python path on that dir in the command ie
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "-m", "PYTHONPATH="/MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/", "/MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/setup.py", "install"])

Comment: A path beginning with a slash is interpreted as an absolute path (beginning at the root). Try `"MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/setup.py"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reading comments made me realize a few mistakes.

First of all I realized that I shouldn't use `-m` flag in this case and this allow me to execute `setup.py` correctly. Also deleted the extra slash in the path and now the following works:

```
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/setup.py", "install"])
```

However, since I wasn't in that directory still, I also got the following error `c1xx: fatal error C1083: It is not possible to open file: 'emd_cuda.cu': No such file or directory` and the compilation failed.

This definitely fixed all the problems:

```
import os
import subprocess

os.chdir("MSN-Point-Cloud-Completion-master/emd/")
subprocess.run([sys.executable, "setup.py", "install"])
```